# Many to Many LSTM in TensorFlow : Training error not decreasing

Tags: tensorflow, sequence, lstm

I am trying to use train an LSTM to behave like a controller. Essential this is a many to many problem. I have 7 input features and with each feature being a sequence of 40 values. My output has two features, also being a sequence of 40 values.

I have 2 layers. First layer has four LSTM cells, and second has two LSTM cells. The code is given below.

The code runs and produces output as expected but I am unable to reduced the training error (Mean square error). The error just stops improving after the first 1000 epochs.

I tried using different batch sizes. But I am getting high error even if it the batch size is one. I tried the same network with a simple sine function, and it is working properly i.e. the error is decreasing. Is this because my sequence length is too large, due to which the vanishing gradient problem is occurring. What can I do to improve training error?

```
#Specify input and ouput features
Xfeatures = 7 #Number of input features
Yfeatures = 2 #Number of input features
num_steps = 40

   # reset everything to rerun in jupyter
tf.reset_default_graph()
# Placeholder for the inputs in a given iteration.
u = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [train_batch_size,num_steps,Xfeatures])
u_NN = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [train_batch_size,num_steps,Yfeatures])

with tf.name_scope('Normalization'):
        #L2 normalization for input data
        Xnorm = tf.nn.l2_normalize(u_opt, 0, epsilon=1e-12, name='Normalize')

lstm1= tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm1_size)
lstm2 = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm2_size)
stacked_lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm1, lstm2])

print(lstm1.output_size)
print(stacked_lstm.output_size)

LSTM_outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(stacked_lstm, Xnorm, dtype=tf.float32)
#Loss
mean_square_error = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(u_NN,LSTM_outputs)
train_step =     tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(mean_square_error)
#Initialization and training session
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    #print(sess.run([LSTM_outputs],feed_dict={u_opt:InputX1}))
    print(sess.run([mean_square_error],feed_dict={u_opt:InputX1,u_NN:InputY1}))
    for i in range(training_epochs):
        sess.run([train_step],feed_dict={u_opt:InputX1,u_NN:InputY1})
        if i%display_epoch ==0:
            print("Training loss is:",sess.run([mean_square_error],feed_dict={u_opt:InputX1,u_NN:InputY1}),"at itertion:",i) 
    print(sess.run([mean_square_error],feed_dict={u_opt:InputX1,u_NN:InputY1}))
    print(sess.run([LSTM_outputs],feed_dict={u_opt:InputX1}))
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with: "First layer has four LSTM cells, and second has two LSTM cells. The code is given below"? Probably you intend the states of the cells.

Your code is not complete but I can try give you some advices.

- If your training error is not going down, a possibility is that your net is not well dimensioned. Probably your `lstm1_size` and `lstm2_size` are not enough large to capture the characteristics of your data.
- LSTMs help you in accumulating the past of a given sequences in a state vector. Usually, the state vector is not used itself as the predictor but it is projected to the output space using a standard feedforward layer. Probably you can just keep a single layer of recursion (a single LSTM layer) and than project the outputs of the layer using a feedforward layer (i.e. g(W*LSTM_outputs+b), where g is a non-linear activation).